# XSLT 1.0: Converting date/time to local timezone

Tags: xslt

My XML has a tag with the two separate properties, `formatted_date` which has day.month.year format (e.g. `formatted_date="02.10.2012"`) and `time` which has a hours:minutes format (e.g. `time="23:00"`).

I'm trying to find a way to convert these somehow to my local timezone. I'm using XSLT 1.0 since PHP-XSL can only support that as far as I understand.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in 'pure' XSLT 1.0, you must use some kind of extension that allow you to call external functions from within the XSLT. This is possible in .NET, that is the environment I am familiar with, but it appears to be possible also in PHP - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php